# Reading special characters from XML in flash

Tags: xml, flash

I have a php file that generates an xml, the php file:

```
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<?php
...
$directorio1 = utf8_encode($directorio);
$dir1 = utf8_encode($dir);
$string = "<nombre>$dir1$directorio1</nombre>\n";
$write = fputs($fp, $string);
...?>
```

An xml generated with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<elementos>
<elemento>
<nombre>PROYECTOS/VIVIENDAS/Arturo Soria/P9120205.JPG</nombre>
<id>0</id>
<tam>376</tam>
</elemento>
...
<elemento>
<nombre>SHOWROOM/DISEÑOS PROPIOS/8099 entera(2).jpg</nombre>
<id>34</id>
<tam>156</tam>
</elemento>
</elementos>
```

In Flash CS5 I try reading and loading from the tag :

```
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
ldr.load(new URLRequest(decodeURIComponent(nombre)));
```

And doesn't find the file for the element containing the Ñ.

I've also tried the following:

```
ldr.load(new URLRequest(escape(nombre)));

ldr.load(new URLRequest(unescape(nombre)));

ldr.load(new URLRequest(nombre));
```

without any success.

I also tried changing the encoding of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

But still not working.
Anyone knows what I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely an encoding issue. You should make sure your resulting XML is properly formatted.

Also, you should change your "nombre" tag, so its text is located inside a CDATA field, otherwise, you may get illegal characters in your file and get error when trying to parse it.